# tool to create a domain model diagram

Tags: diagrams

My requirement is to create a diagram which can represent the object relationship which is stored in an xml.

For example

This needs to get translated as Class abc has a field which is xyz. This heirarchy can be multi level. and we need to represent 
a) high level struturing of classes
b) contents of these classes.

I looked at some tools like umlet, violet, visio. but all of these require a lot of manual intervention. Is there a tool which can be configured to read from xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Graphviz and the dot language.

http://www.graphviz.org/

You'll need to write a translation layer, but that shouldn't be too hard in the language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried GraphWiz and it turned out to be perfect for my requirement. Moreover the dot language is extremely simple .

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted with the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

UModel might be a good pick for you on this one... http://www.altova.com/umodel/xml-schemas-in-uml.html